# How to find a particular dll is threadsafe or not ? Ant API/tool for this?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, thread-safety

For example, i downloaded [Gecko 1.9.1](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/1.9.1.7/sdk/xulrunner-1.9.1.7.en-US.win32.sdk.zip) SDK.

It contains js3250.dll.

How i can be sure that this dll is thread-safe?

Advance Thanks

-Parimal Das

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to read the documentation of the particular library.

Comment: And if the document says nothing about thread safety, assume it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

If there was such a tool then we would all be using it on our threaded code.  Such a tool is impossible to write.  You can flag questionable features, so you can say that a particular piece of code is *not* thread safe, but cannot guarantee that it is.  Working at the object code level in a dll would make the problem even more difficult.